# How to select rows using relationships between their values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say that i have a data frame with the following content:

```
input,output
30,10
13,33
86,37
```

how do i select the rows where input is greater than output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the boolean comparison as a mask:

```
In [130]:
df[df['input']>df['output']]

Out[130]:
   input  output
0     30      10
2     86      37
```

There is also the `gt` which means greater than:

```
In [133]:
df[df['input'].gt(df['output'])]

Out[133]:
   input  output
0     30      10
2     86      37
```

Comment: thanks! i still do not get for which magic of the python interpreter this is working

Comment: Sorry can you clarify your comment

Comment: well that would be another question. `df['input'] > df['output']` seems to be treated as a lambda, instead of being evaluated

Comment: wow could you adjust the indentation a bit please? this way it is not very readable. thanks

Comment: Your comment doesn't make much sense the mask `df['input'] > df['output']` is no different to my last edit, we call operator `>` on the series `df['input']` passing `df['output']` as the param, this will return a boolean series which we can use to filter the df

Comment: This is ipython output, it's clear which parts are inputs and which parts are output, most python users understand this

Comment: @danza When you say "treated as a lambda", do you mean how the comparison happens for each element of both columns automatically? That's "vectorization", it's one of the main benefits of Pandas. The same idea shows up in `numpy` and in other data analysis software like R.

Comment: @EdChum wow thanks for answering also my other question! Yeah that is arithmetics between series, i did not realise! I thought that the expression was somehow extracted and evaluated on every row as a lambda. About indentation, i use ipython as well, and commands follow the `In []:` line, separated by one space. Just Stack Overflow would not allow to edit such a small thing, it does not matter

Comment: I can pad it out a bit